# Swift: Can't get UITextField to dismiss keyboard

Tags: swift, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have two `textFields` and a `Done` button in my VC but I'm having some problems with the ending of editing.

My `textFieldDidEndEditing` method is called when I tap on one `textField` after being inside the other one, or when I tap outside the textField (because I added a tap recognizer to the parent view) but not when I tap the `Done` button.

And, most important (especially when I run on an actual device), the keyboard won't disappear under any of these circumstances, even though my `textFieldDidEndEditing` method calls `resignFirstResponder()`.

Why isn't the keyboard dismissing? Also, is there a way to have `textFieldDidEndEditing` get called when I tap outside the field just automatically (without having it come from the tap recognizer)? It just seems like this should be how it works, but if I'm wrong, I'm wrong.

Here's some pertinent parts of my code.

1.Trying to dismiss the keyboard. The first part of this method works, and the value is stored (when the method is called at all, that is). At no point does the cursor disappear from the textField, nor does the keyboard get dismissed.

```
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let playerName = textField.text, let playerNum = nameFields.index(of: textField) {
        playerNames[playerNum] = playerName
    }
    resignFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textFieldDidEndEditing(textField)
    return true
}
```

Also, here's a curious thing: when I set a breakpoint in `textFieldDidEndEditing` and debug, enter a value in one field and hit `Done`, it segues to the next scene, and *then* stops at `textFieldDidEndEditing`, which at this point has no effect (the values may be stored but they aren't reflected in the new scene).

2.Trying to add the tap recognizer to the done button. I don't have an outlet to the done button in my code, just out of laziness, so that's probably the best solution. But, I'm still interested in why this doesn't work. This is identical to the code that defines the tap recognizer that's working in the parent view.

```
func dismiss(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    nameFields.forEach { textFieldDidEndEditing($0) }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    for view in view.subviews where view is UIButton {
        let dismissTextField = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss(_:)))
        dismissTextField.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTextField)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `resignFirstResponder` inside `textFieldShouldReturn` method instead of calling `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Also in your `TapGesture` method simply call [`endEditing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting) with your `view` instead of looping through the array of textFields.

```
func dismiss(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Oh my god I'm so dumb. I was calling it in the right spot, but I wasn't calling it on anything. Simply changing `resignFirstResponder()` to `textField.resignFirstResponder()` fixed everything. Well, that and adding an outlet action for the done button in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5:  This solution below is much easier actually.

Simply subclass your ViewController with the text fields to UITextFieldDelegate like this:

```
class CreateGroupViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

then if you named your UITextFields:  nameTextField & occupationTextField then add the following delegations to your viewDidLoad() method:

```
self.nameTextField.delegate = self
self.occupationTextField.delegate = self
```

Then simply add the generic function to your file:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

If you do it this way, then for every textField reference outlet you create, all of them will hide the keyboard after the user hits the return button no matter which textField he's typing.  For each textField you add to your view, add another self.nextTextField.delegate = self line to your viewDidLoad.

Remember to test this with your iPhone/iDevice plugged into your developer computer bc XCode's simulator doesn't bring up the keyboard (bc you're normally testing using a full keyboard).  Or if you've set up your testing hardware (iPhone) via WiFi you can do it that way also.  Otherwise, your users will be "testing" this on TestFlight.